# Salesforce to Azure Data warehouse - string truncated

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We are using Azure data factory to copy data from Salesforce to Azure Data warehouse. The job is getting failed since some values are getting truncated .The source column in Salesforce is of type Long Text area(32000). What will be equivalent data type in Azure data warehouse to accommodate this data from Salesforce ?

Comment: Are you using the PolyBase or bulkinsert writer within ADF?

Comment: Bulk insert within ADF.

Comment: I have to question the wisdom of storing text this long in a data warehouse.  It's not like you can aggregate it or put it in a dimension or `GROUP BY`.  If you really want to do something with the text, like analytics, sentiment analysis, named entity recognition etc consider placing this data in Azure Data Lake and using the cognitive libraries as per the fantastic examples [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-cognitive).  You could then store the summarised outputs in the warehouse, even report from them, which would make sense.

Comment: I have to agreed @wBob

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer. Don't store 32,000 char fields in a data warehouse! :-)

Comment: Though it might look weird requirement I would like to know whether its technically possible in Azure Data WareHouse?